# Alternative code position for Django admin list display settings

Tags: python, django

I am following the tutorial of Django 1.6, which includes a model `Poll` that has a derived attribute `was_published_recently` (a method of `class Poll`).  The model was originally defined as follows.

```
# polls/models.py (excerpted)

class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

And the admin interface for this app:

```
# polls/admin.py (excerpted)

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Now we want to improve the display and sorting functionality of `was_published_recently`.

In the tutorial, file `polls/models.py` is updated:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

However, I think this may not be good enough in practice, because what we are specifying is completely about the admin user interface, not the model per se.  So I instead updated `polls/admin.py`:

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    Poll.was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    Poll.was_published_recently.boolean = True
    Poll.was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
    # ...
```

After this modification, the app works as expected as well (multiple polls work well also). Since I am new to Python, I investigated a bit further by printing `was_published_recently` in both `Poll` and `PollAdmin`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    print("in class Poll", was_published_recently)

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    print("in class PollAdmin", Poll.was_published_recently)
    # ...
```

And the output is

```
in class Poll <function Poll.was_published_recently at 0x10fc92050>
in class PollAdmin <function Poll.was_published_recently at 0x10fc92050>
```

So apparently `was_published_recently` in `class Poll` is the same as `Poll.published_recently` accessed in `class PollAdmin`.

My question: Should I specify the `admin_order_field` stuffs in `admin.py` or `models.py`?  If specified in `admin.py` instead of `models.py`, are there any drawbacks?

Comment: Does it work correctly? Did you try with multiple `Poll` objects?, because `Poll.was_published_recently.admin_order_field` it different  then defining `was_published_recently.admin_order_field` in class. Because A class itself is a object so by writing `Poll.was_published_recently` you adding attribute to class but not class's object

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes it works correctly even with multiple `Poll` objects.

Comment: No idea :( if its working then + good question.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Hah thanks :-)  I also investigated further by printing two `was_published_recently` occurrences and the output shows that they are the same object at the time being accessed.

Comment: My concept is not very much good but I have doubt that defining in your way is different then given in tutorials. Not sure but try..add some more objects, give it a try again.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Added 100 more poll objects, and still works well.  Also for each of the poll objects, e.g. `p`, `print(p.was_published_recently)` shows something like `<bound method Poll.was_published_recently of <Poll: Question 99>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, everything is working as intended, and it's semantically the same to put `admin_order_field` stuffs either in `models.py` or `admin.py`.

> So apparently was_published_recently in class Poll is the same as Poll.published_recently accessed in class PollAdmin.

Yes. They should be the same. Classes are objects. So `Poll` is an object. `Poll.was_published_recently` is an attribute of object `Poll`, and is also an object with type `instancemethod`. Wherever you access it, it is the same object.

AFAIK, the only difference between writing `admin_order_field` stuffs in `models.py` and `admin.py` is the order of interpretation. Django loads `models.py` before `admin.py`, so everything runs at loading time and relies on `admin_order_field` stuffs will fail. But since `admin_order_field` is only used in `admin.py`, I think what you are doing is fine.

Python is so dynamic that allows you to modify definitions from even other modules. This can lead to hard-to-find bugs and bad readability / maintainability. Be sure to use this black magic with caution.